# How to compare excel data with JSON response by iterating through each row in excel in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I want compare excel data with JSON response by iterating through each row in excel in JMeter

Consider below data is available in excel

Last_Name|  ID   |  First_Name 
Lawson   |    7  |  Michael
Funke    |    9  |Tobias
Thomas   |    6  |James
Green    |    5  |Rachel

Below is the JSON Response:

```
        {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Michael",
            "last_name": "Lawson",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
        }
```

Now I want to iterate through each row in excel and compare each row with JSON response and then display result if the JSON response is matching with any of the row in excel or not.
Combination should be Last_name, ID and First_Name.This should match.
Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

1. If by "Excel" you mean CSV you can read the values from file into JMeter Variables using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
2. If by "Excel" you mean "Excel" like .xls or .xlsx - you can use Apache POI library to read the values from it into JMeter Variables, see the following references:

   - [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter)
   - [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
3. You can extract the values from the JSON response using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)
4. And finally you can use [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to compare the variables originating from JSON and Excel:

   [image]